# How to change the characters output by hline/vline?

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am trying to create a border around a window with hline/vline. My desired output is as follows

[image]

But instead I get letters such as `q` and `m` being used as the border.

Here is my code so far:

```
mvwhline(white_space, 0, 3, ACS_HLINE, 10);
```

How do I use lines instead of letters? 
Thanks!

Comment: It's a _long_ time since I did anything with [n]curses, but when I was drawing boxes (albeit character by character instead of with `mvwhline()`), I had to do `wattron( w, A_ALTCHARSET );` before and `wattroff( w, A_ALTCHARSET );` afterwards (where `w` is the `WINDOW*`).

Comment: Could you provide me with an example of this? I am struggling to understand A_ALTCHARSET  Thanks!

Comment: It's what I had in some old source file... I assumed it was a curses `#define` but I won't be able to check until tomorrow morning. The purpose (IIRC) was to switch to an/the alternate character set (where the line-drawing characters are).

Comment: Just checked: `A_ALTCHARSET` was "just part of curses" when I was using it, and could either be set as an attribute as above or `|`ed with a character.  There's some mention of it [here](http://melvilletheatre.com/articles/ncurses-extended-characters/index.html) and [this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1421240) seems to be addressing the same problem, and as Thomas Dickey says in his answer, the terminal type can affect things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual problem is from using terminal descriptions using VT100 line-drawing with terminals which do not support that feature.  If the question showed a complete program, it would be simple to test it and see if there were some other issue.

ncurses makes checks for "linux" and "screen", but not everything.  PuTTY is another example, so ncurses provides an environment variable to handle these cases: [`NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS).  That feature was added in [late 2011](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20050312) (some very old distributions before [ncurses 5.6](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#other_versions) may not work, for example).  Note also that ssh normally drops unusual environment variables, for (again using PuTTY as an example), it may not be possible to preset this variable in the client setting up the connection.

For programs which do *not* support VT100 line-drawing, ncurses may use ASCII graphics (non-letter characters such as `|` and `-`) to draw lines as noted in the [`waddch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Line-Graphics) manual page.  If your locale uses UTF-8 encoding, you must use the "ncurses**w**" library to make ncurses use UTF-8 characters as an alternate to ASCII graphics.

Comment: Ah I see thanks for your answer. I read up here: http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-linedraw and it says PuTTY cannot handle VT100 line-drawing which is a bit of a disappointment but I guess I will have to use | and _ .

Comment: But PuTTY usually can handle Unicode line-drawing (not always, but that would be a good topic for a bug report to PuTTY's developers).